# Can't import between files in the same folder

Tags: python, import

I'm trying to import Entity.py into Tower.py in the same directory, in order to instantiate the Entity class inside Tower.py. However, it keeps coming up with the same error.

```
folder
  |_ scripts
       |_ Tower.py
       |_ Entity.py
  |_ Main.py
```

Entity.py

```
class Entity:
   ...
```

Tower.py

```
import Entity
```

```
 File "C:\...\scripts\Tower.py", line 3, in <module>
    import Entity
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Entity'
```

I'm confused as to why this is happening and what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Is this error caused by running Tower.py or Main.py?

Comment: I ran Main.py, but the error was raised from Tower.py: it couldn't import Entity.py. However, using from .Entity import Entity solved the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modules are relative to the working directory. So, if you are running the app using `Main.py`, every import will be relative to the directory of Main.py.

If you want to import the Entity to Tower, you must import it like

```
from scripts.Entity import Entity
```

or with relative like

```
from .Entity import Entity
```

And you must create a `__init__.py` file in your `scripts` folder to mark it as a package.

Answer (score 0):

The Module should be in the same subfolder too.

```
folder
        Wrong X scripts
  | Tower.py
  | Entity.py
  |_ Main.py
```